# How do I connect to the SLOBS pipe for json-rpc?

Tags: javascript, api, pipe, obs

I want to use the Streamlabs OBS API found at https://stream-labs.github.io/streamlabs-obs-api-docs/docs/index.html. It says to send the requests to the "named slobs pipe", but I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe they're referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes. So, there would be a file on the local filesystem at `\\.\pipe\slobs` that you could communicate with. Where/how is your code running?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231534/named-pipe-communication-between-node-js-and-net

Comment: I don't currently have any code, but I would prefer doing it in node.js because I already have the socket api in node.

Comment: In that case, take a look at the question I've linked to there, it's a way to connect to named pipes from NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you. I see it.